# Fitnesse server not opening tests suite from src/test/fitnesse

Tags: maven, fitnesse

For below Maven plugin. wehn I try to run 
**mvn verify -DskipTests -P wiki**

Fitnesse Server launches with default FrontPage Suite not with MyTest.
I want to launch server that should open MyTest suite, so that I can edit that make changes directly in src/test/fitnesse folder directly

```
 <profile>
            <id>wiki</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>uk.co.javahelp.fitnesse</groupId>
                        <artifactId>fitnesse-launcher-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <port>9122</port>
                            <workingDir>${project.build.directory}/fitnesse</workingDir>
                            <root>FitNesseRoot</root>
                            <testResourceDirectory>src/test/fitnesse</testResourceDirectory>
                            <reportsDir>${project.build.directory}/fitnesse/reports</reportsDir>
                            <resultsDir>${project.build.directory}/fitnesse/results</resultsDir>
                            <summaryFile>${project.build.directory}/fitnesse/results/failsafe-summary.xml</summaryFile>
                            <createSymLink>true</createSymLink>
                            <excludeOptionalDependencies>true</excludeOptionalDependencies> <!-- Deprecated -->
                            <deletePluginsProperties>false</deletePluginsProperties> <!-- Note the 's' in "plugins" -->
                            <alwaysUnpackFitnesse>false</alwaysUnpackFitnesse>
                            <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
                            <useProjectDependencies>
                                <!-- Any combination of scopes -->
                                <scope>system</scope>
                                <scope>compile</scope>
                                <scope>provided</scope>
                                <scope>runtime</scope>
                                <scope>test</scope>
                            </useProjectDependencies>
                            <launches>
                                <launch>
                                    <suite>MyTest</suite>
                                </launch>
                            </launches>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>set-up</goal>
                                    <goal>wiki</goal>
                                    <goal>tear-down</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below configuration in Configuration tag

```
<configuration> 
                        <suite>YourSuitePageName</suite>                    
</configuration>
```